# Como exportar/importar base de datos Room

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room, room

Tengo una pequeña base de datos Room en una app y quisiera poder exportar e importarla (a modo de Backup). ¿Hay alguna forma rápida? De momento sólo he encontrado exportar tabla a tabla por ejemplo a un csv para luego importar también tabla a tabla...

Un saludo

Comment: ¿Como realizas la exportación a CSV? , agrega esta información a tu pregunta.

Comment: Hola! Precisamente el "apaño" que he encontrado de hacerlo en CSV tabla a tabla no me parece nada práctico, imagino que habrá alguna clase que permita hacer una exportación/importación directamente...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es una solución usando las propias herramientas de Room o de Android pero parece ser que funciona.

Primero se debe definir el Journal Mode de la base de datos como Truncate, si no recuerdo mal esta configuración fuerza que la base de datos se cree en un único fichero. Siendo "my-database" el nombre que le deis a la base de datos, por ejemplo:

```
 return Room.databaseBuilder(context,
                AppDatabase.class,
                "my-database")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .setJournalMode(RoomDatabase.JournalMode.TRUNCATE)
                .build();
```

Después se puede coger la base de datos con la instrucción:

```
getDatabasePath("my-database").getAbsolutePath()
```

Y se puede mover a cualquier otra ubicación. Para recuperar la BD simplemente hay que poner el archivo copiado en la ruta original. Así lo copio en la exportación:

```
  String currentDBPath = context.getDatabasePath("my-database").getAbsolutePath();

try {
  File currentDB = new File(currentDBPath);
  File backupDB = new File(PATHBACKUP, "my-database.db");
  copy(currentDB, backupDB);
}catch(IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```